# PHP Get Decimal number

Tags: php, laravel

in my blade, I write this code

```
{{($sub /$Tot)*100 }}%
```

My output is

```
42.857142857143%
```

I need to get output in this format

```
42%
```

i tried this code below but i get same value

```
{{round(($sub /$Tot)*100) }}%
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue there. https://3v4l.org/YTuPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your round should be for the overall output, try this

```
 $output = (25/47)*100;
 echo round($output);
```

Comment: thanks, it worked fine but what if I need to get 42.8%

Comment: `round($output,1)`

Answer (score 0):

use the `int` value of decimal number,

```
$value = (int)$decimal;
```

i.e. in view,

```
{{(int)(($sub /$Tot)*100) }}%
```

Answer (score 0):

`round` will give the closest value. `(int)` will give the closest value in the direction of 0. The following should give you 42 instead of 43.

```
{{(int)(($sub /$Tot)*100) }}%
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for PHP's [floor()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) function.

```
{{ floor(($sub /$Tot)*100) }}%
```